# Rails/Active Record - I'm not sure of what to do with data that is innate to my application rather than user-provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I realize that title probably sounds a little confusing. Hopefully I can clarify.

Suppose I have static product category information (e.g., category titles such as "TVs," "Computers," "Cell Phones," etc.). These aren't user-submitted data; these are categories that exist by default within the database. Maybe each category (or category record, since we're talking databases) has both a name and description property. This, again, is something that exists by default within the site, so I'd probably have to enter these values manually.

No problem.

What's a bit confusing to me is how to go about adding this to the database so that it's always there, even if, during development of my application, I need to work across multiple computers and need to provide each computer access to the same default data. Also, once the application is finally in production, this default data would need to be present, too.

I hope this is clear and not too clumsily worded. Basically, I just want to know how to seed my database with data, not just for testing in development but also for use in production. I realize Rails has seed.rb, but I've heard that that is to be used merely for stub data. I need to figure out how to seed my database for real and how to essentially pull down a copy of it as I would pull down code from Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right. I did some more searching, and the answers are here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data